# Phalcon Initialize() is not working

Tags: phalcon

I have 2 Controllers, `TEST1Controller` and `TEST2Controller`

In `TEST2Controller` I have a `initialize()` function setting value of a property.

If I try to access `TEST2Controller` directly from the browser, everything works perfectly.

But when I call a `TEST2Controller` method from `TEST1Controller`, it seems that `initialize()` function is not being called in `TEST2Controller`.

`TEST1Controller`:

```
namespace Modcont\Controller;

use Modcont\Controller\Test2Controller;

class Test1Controller extends BaseController
{

    function gettestAction()
    {
       $t = new Test2Controller(); // calling TEST2 Controller Method Within TEST1 Controller
       echo $t->dotestAction(" MYAPP ");
    }    
}
```

`TEST2Controller`:

```
namespace Modcont\Controller;

class Test2Controller extends BaseController
{   
    public $prefix;
    function initialize()
    {
        $this->prefix = 'your name is';
    }

    function dotestAction($name)
    {
        return $this->prefix.' : '.$name; 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phalcon offers two ways for controller initialization, thy are the `initialize` and `onContruct` methods. The basic difference between these two methods is that `initialize` is called **only** when a controller is created by the framework to proceed with the execution of an action. Since you instantiating a controller object *ad-hoc*, `initialize` will not be called, only `onConstruct` will. So you'll need to put your initialization logic there:

```
function onConstruct()
{
    $this->prefix = 'your name is';
}
```

Also, implementing native constructors in controller is discouraged, but if you do so, make sure to call the parent constructor in your own constructor: `parent::__construct();`.

All this information can be found [in the Docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/controllers.html#initializing-controllers).